# How to disable notification popup in Chrome Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.arttoframe.com/")
time.sleep(6)
driver.close()
```

Console Logs :

```
C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/untitled/newaaa.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have created an instance of `ChromeOptions()` as **chrome_options** you need to pass it as an argument to put the configurations in effect while invoking `webdriver.Chrome()` as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.arttoframe.com/")
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

**Note** :

- To maximize the Chrome browser instead of `maximize_window()` use the `ChromeOptions()` class argument **start-maximized**
- At the end of your program instead of `driver.close()` use **driver.quit()**.

Comment: Thank You very very much I am very happy now because of you, thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.switch_to_alert().dismiss()
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

These can be used dismiss-right and accept-left

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.