# Options().add_experimental_option does not work

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I've been working on a script to automate a task in Google Chrome. Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck in giving Chrome access to my microphone and denying access to notifications. I have tried using `Options().add_experimental_option()` but without any luck. Am I doing something wrong or is there another way? I have tried using fake UI and fake media stream to remove the popup, but that hasn't worked either. `Options().add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"); Options().add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Options().binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Options().add_argument("start-maximized");
Options().add_argument("--disable-infobars")
# 1 to allow, 2 to block
Options().add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})
driver=webdriver.Chrome(".\chromedriver.exe", options=Options())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all the *attributes*, *arguments* and *experimental option* within a single instance of `Options` and pass as an argument while initiating the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) / [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) combo as follows:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
# 1 to allow, 2 to block
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
   "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})
driver=webdriver.Chrome(".\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to allow or deny notification geo-location microphone camera pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007699/how-to-allow-or-deny-notification-geo-location-microphone-camera-pop-up/48017495#48017495)
- [How to disable notification popup in Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626707/how-to-disable-notification-popup-in-chrome-browser/49626861#49626861)